# Android simulation in windows using python

Tags: android, python-3.x, windows, operating-system

HI I am searching for this long time but not getting any proper answer
Is it Possible to run the android application in the windows using python?

Comment: how exactly you want to use python for that?

Comment: like I can execute a single Android application using python

Comment: what you mean by *execute*? You can run an emulator, and send commands to it suing some python code, but you have to be more specific on what exactly you want to do to get more detiled answer

Comment: ok sir  i mean can python simulates apk or can we create android emulator?

Comment: In theory, you can create Android emulator using Python, but : 1) it will take you probably couple years to do that. 2) It makes no sense, as there already are many emulators available, and you don't need to create another one.

Comment: ok sir means we can create our own android emulator using python?

Comment: yes, but as I said - it makes no sense to do that

Comment: Agreed but you know some psycho I am the one XD